# vscode live Server port settings not work, and always open in localhost:8081

Tags: visual-studio-code, port, liveservertestcase

here is my live Server settings json

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "vetur.format.options.useTabs": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "git.autofetch": false,
    "liveServer.settings.host": "localhost",
    "liveServer.settings.port": 0,

}
```

I try to reinstall live Server and close the windows firewall, but it still not work.

It drives me mad!

Comment: But not Port settings in your configuración file. Try: liveServer.settings.port": 9015  to listen on 9015  or any number.

Answer (score 5):

Look at your workspace , in the .vscode/settings.json ,you may find the "liveServer.settings.port":8081 in it. Just delete it

Comment: yap, it was the workspace settings causing all the problems for me. Thx!

Comment: This file is created after launching a live server instance when there is already an instance running from a different VSCode window.  Very helpful to know how to remedy.